# How to set special character (UTF-8) in java String and xml?

Tags: java, dom, special-characters, jdom

I want to save special character (UTF-8) in java.
In my JSF page I am setting string value in model

```
<h:inputTextarea id="que" value="#{dataModel.question}"/>
```

When I am going to fetch that String in my java controller that time this give 
different character eg. I have sentence like ΔLMN ≠ΔXYZ when I am printing the value 
in controller that time it prints like ΔLMN ≠ΔXYZ.
 
In my project I am fetch the value from XML file and write the same value in XML like

```
option.addContent(new CDATA(new String(this.launchModel.getQuestionList().get(i).getOptionList().get(k).getOption().getBytes("UTF-8"), "UTF-8")));
```

How to sovle this problem..I am trting my side..

Comment: what is the difference?

Comment: Add encoding value in your cml tag <?xml encoding="UTF-8" ?>

Comment: `ΔLMN ≠ΔXYZ` vs `ΔLMN ≠ΔXYZ` - I would ask for my money back

Comment: @Ronak..I have already done in my XML file.

Comment: sry it prints like &#916;LMN &#8800;&#916;XYZ

Comment: Where is it printing, and what code are you using to do the printing?

Comment: if u are print in controller then it comes